# How to update a column based on date condition from another column?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my initial test table

| IdRecord | FechaRegistro | IdDimFecCorte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-25 23:45:00.000 | 20220430 |
| 2 | 2022-04-24 18:07:00.000 | 20220430 |
| 3 | 2022-03-10 19:04:00.000 | 20220331 |
| 4 | 2022-03-22 16:55:00.000 | 20220331 |
| 5 | 2022-02-10 22:06:00.000 | 20220331 |
| 6 | 2022-02-14 02:06:00.000 | 20220331 |
| 7 | 2022-01-30 21:55:00.000 | 20220331 |

I need to run an update in that table so the column `IdDimFecCorte` shows the date (as an type integer) of the last day of the month based on the date from column `FechaRegistro` .
As you can see, records 1,2,3,4 already satisfy this requirement but I require to run it retrospectively (for example with records 5,6,7)

My desired output should be

| IdRecord | FechaRegistro | IdDimFecCorte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-25 23:45:00.000 | 20220430 |
| 2 | 2022-04-24 18:07:00.000 | 20220430 |
| 3 | 2022-03-10 19:04:00.000 | 20220331 |
| 4 | 2022-03-22 16:55:00.000 | 20220331 |
| 5 | 2022-02-10 22:06:00.000 | 20220228 |
| 6 | 2022-02-14 02:06:00.000 | 20220228 |
| 7 | 2022-01-30 21:55:00.000 | 20220131 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=56016083492a05999063fa1192af7d47)

Comment: Good time to visit the documentation or search "sql server date functions". We have [EOMONTH()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Don't really understand your use of "batch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to do this.

```
select IdRecord,FechaRegistro, CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH(FechaRegistro),'-','') as INT) IdDimFecCorte from dbo.fact1Desired
```

if you want to update all.

```
UPDATE dbo.fact1Desired
    SET IdDimFecCorte = CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH(dbo.fact1Desired.FechaRegistro),'-','') as INT)
```

If you want to have it automatic while adding.

```
INSERT dbo.fact1Desired(IdRecord,FechaRegistro,IdDimFecCorte)
VALUES (1, '20220425 23:45:00.000', CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH('20220425 23:45:00.000'),'-','') as INT)),
       (2, '20220424 18:07:00.000', CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH('20220424 18:07:00.000'),'-','') as INT)),
       (3, '20220310 19:04:00.000', CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH('20220310 19:04:00.000'),'-','') as INT)),
       (4, '20220322 16:55:00.000', CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH('20220322 16:55:00.000'),'-','') as INT)),
       (5, '20220210 22:06:00.000', CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH('20220210 22:06:00.000'),'-','') as INT)),--
       (6, '20220214 02:06:00.000', CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH('20220214 02:06:00.000'),'-','') as INT)),--
       (7, '20220130 21:55:00.000', CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH('20220130 21:55:00.000'),'-','') as INT))--
;
```